# Deployment branch ahead of master branch

Tags: git, github

I am having a master branch, and a deployment branch. After I finalise all the changes in the master branch, I would merge the master branch into the deployment branch to deploy it. However, the problem is that everytime I deploy, there would be an additional commit in the deployment branch "Merge pull request from master". As a result, my deployment branch would be x commits ahead of master branch, with x being the times I have deployed it.

This is very annoying, and while I can (and I occasionally do) solve it by merging the deployment branch back into the master branch, but it is essentially a pull request that does nothing. What should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: In your scenario, usually a merge of master into deploy should be a fast-forward. This is usually not the case if deploy had diverged from master at some time in the past. Did this happen?

Comment: Nope, the deployment branch is always updated by merging from the master branch via a pull request.

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of a fast-forward. Is it something I should be doing instead of merging via pull request?

Comment: Can you go back and have a look at when the first time a non-ff-merge happened?

Comment: A merge automatically becomes a fast-forward (meaning it creates no merge commits) if the two branches haven't diverged. At some point there must have been a divergence, otherwise Git whould have simply performed a ff.

Comment: Why do you need a deployment branch and not deploy directly from `master`?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev it's like an additional layer of fail-safe for me. It is like a pre-deployment branch for me, where I test out everything before deploying. My master branch deploys to a separate "testing" server where I go through final round of checking before deploying the actual thing.

Comment: @NilsWerner thanks for the information! I didn't know that. I have thousands of commits by now though, would probably be impractical to compare all of them to find the divergence. Could I just delete the current deployment branch, make a new one from the current master branch as my new deployment branch? Then all further pull requests should be fast-forwarded right?

Comment: @Samson, are you using Github for pull requests ?

Comment: @Samson, the safest (and the most up-to-date) option is not to build the binary again after you tested it. Instead you should release the **same binary** that was tested.

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Yes I am using Github.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **GitHub** for pull requests, here's a quote from the [help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request) :

> Pull requests are merged using the --no-ff option, except for pull
>   requests with squashed or rebased commits, which are merged using the
>   fast-forward option.

In case you are creating merge commits which will lead to separate commits like `Merge pull request from master`, you might want to rebase and merge your pull requests.

> When you select the Rebase and merge option on a pull request on
>   GitHub, all commits from the topic branch (or head branch) are added
>   onto the base branch individually without a merge commit. Pull
>   requests with rebased commits are merged using the fast-forward
>   option.

**Reference** : [help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#rebase-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits)

Comment: I have tried this, and while it did not create a commit message, the branch still shows "this branch is x commits ahead of master and y commits behind"

Comment: So the changes has been pulled, but github still shows it being ahead/behind